# how to create custom splash screen in uwp to add gif image

Tags: c#-4.0, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on an app and I want to add gif image on splash screen but it only takes png or jpg image.I have tried to add gif but automaticaly converts gif animation to stationary image.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a page that will acts as a fake splashscreen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen